# XMPP JID seems like always null

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I use XMPP to build a chat application. While attempting to log in, I see that my JID instance is always null. I thus can connect the server but I cannot properly authenticate.

```
self.xmppStream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"efeuser"];
NSLog(@"%@",self.xmppStream.myJID.user);
```

It logs `myJID` as null.

I also tried to create a new user on Openfire with register packet, but the user JID is also null.

```
 <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" to="bowerchat.com/3df1adfc">
  <query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
   <username/>
   <password>efe1414</password>
  </query>
  <error code="500" type="wait">
   <internal-server-error xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
  </error>
 </iq>
```

Answer (score 1):

JIDs can be of two forms:

```
user@example.com
example.com
```

If they include an `@`, then the part before the `@` is the userpart. But the userpart may also be left out, as it is in the second example. This is usually used to address the host directly.

```c
self.xmppStream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"efeuser"];
```

This creates a new JID `efeuser` with no userpart. This means:

```c
NSLog(@"%@",self.xmppStream.myJID.user);
```

Prints `(null)` correctly, as there is no userpart.